# What is the equivalent of Metamask in production?

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask

I have used Metamask in test but what can I use for production? Users will not have a metamask extension and we cannot expect them to install it.

What is the standard way to check the account balance of the sender of the message to the contract and also confirm the private/public keys for the user of the contract?

This would be something like MEW in terms of actual processing of the security aspects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Dapp to be truly decentralized, you need your users to be able to connect to a node of their choosing. That does require running a (light) ethereum client, like MetaMask or Mist. Or, if they own a hardware wallet, like Ledger or Trezor, it's possible to use them instead.

However, to enable users to use your Dapp even though they don't have a client running, you could set up your own node, and have your Dapp communicate with it. This would require your users to provide your Dapp with their private keys in order to sign transactions and send those to your node.

Although the private keys don't ever need to leave the user's computer, in my opinion it's still a big security risk. An attacker could set up a phishing website that looks identical to your Dapp, but collect any private keys entered.

I think Dapps should never ask for private keys. Only for already signed transactions and addresses, like MetaMask, Mist and hardware wallets can provide.

So, in short, you should require your users to install MetaMask or own a hardware wallet in order to use your Dapp, even, or should I say especially, in a production environment.

Comment: What about for mobile apps?

Comment: How about this? https://trustwalletapp.com/

Comment: Even though I agree with the "truly decentralized part" I disagree with the rest to some extend. What if you for example have a native app and your key is stored inside that native application and you just sign transactions in your code, then the key would never be exposed anywhere. I would also assert that MetaMask is in no way more secure because the keys are also stored inside your browser (which is insecure). So to conclude I'd say using for example eth-lightwallet and a safe place (i guess finding that place is the main issue) to store the private key is a lot more secure.